# Spring 4.2 @EventListener misses events published from @PostConstruct method

Tags: java, spring, events

I've encountered an interesting issue when `@EventListener` loses events emitted from `@PostConstruct`.

Take a look at [sample code](https://github.com/piotrglazar/night-owl/tree/feautre/new-event-listener/src/main/java/com/piotrglazar/nightowl/test).

There is a ConfigurationPublisher bean that emits first event in a `@PostConstruct` method. Subsequent events are emitted every second using Timer utility from JDK.

There are also two event listeners. NewStyleReceiver uses the `@EventListener` annotation and OldStyleReceiver implements the ApplicationListener interface.

After running the main method from the App class we can see that the first event was received only by OldStyleReceiver.

What can I do to receive events from `@PostConstruct` method via `@EventListener`?

Comment: I guess the issue comes from the fact that it uses annotations and you are using annotation scanning. Both are components and are detected there is no guarantee that the listener is already loaded before your component is loaded, next to that before beans can be scanned for `@EventListener` the context must have finished loading all your beans (see the [`EventListenerMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerMethodProcessor.html).